# AJAX throws error at beginning of html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image]

This is the error that has been getting at me all day. It also happens when I try to fetch the data with requirejs. I have deleted the first two scripts on template.

I have been trying for hours to figure out why this is happening. I am trying to make a rest call with AJAX, but the code gets terminated right away at the doctype declaration. It is turning the hello.js file and the other .js file into routes as shown in the picture, and I dont know why. 
For the record, I have tried changing the script tage to text/html, tried removing or substituting the tags

Here is the template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/animate.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/html"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "hello.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

{{{ body }}}

</body>
</html>
```

hello.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("dalkfdjslakfjdsklfajsdjsalkfsdaklfj");
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: './srch.js',
  dataType: "json"


})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML=data;

})
.fail(function() {
  alert("Ajax failed to fetch data")
}) 
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are there three `<script>` files trying to import jQuery? (The first one, with `type="text/html"`, won't do anything, but still ...)

Comment: Also the directory contents are not relevant - what matters is the paths that your server considers to be correct. Your URLs expect the JavaScript files to be directly available at the top level of the path hierarchy, and you're getting 404s. That means they're not there, so it's not loading or running any of your JavaScript at all.

Comment: The script are inside of the "script" folder, not at the root. Look at the path it's saying it looked in in the error message. It's not looking inside the "script" folder. Prepend "scripts/" to your local path.

Comment: you load from a cdn but you console shows localhost

Comment: @Mihai See the new picture up top

Comment: @Pointy See the new picture at the top

Comment: Look in the "Network" view. That will let you see what the actual contents are of every HTTP transaction. Look for the one that's fetching "hello.js" and see what the response contents actually look like. It could be an HTML-formatted error page from your web server.

Comment: Wait, no; what is actually *in* the "hello.js" file? The image you added shows that the browser fetched the HTML source. Maybe you should start with a *much* simpler example and see if you can get a plain "Hello World" page to load properly in your setup.

Comment: @Pointy I checked the network, under the "all" tab. Only the the 3 css sheets I am using show up. See edit above, where I add what is "in" the hello.js file, IE what it is trying to access. hello.js is also above for reference.

Comment: What do you see when you put the exact URL for "hello.js" (as reported in the Network view) in the browser URL bar on a new empty browser tab?

Comment: @Pointy  See new pictures above... thank you for helping me with this by the way. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I see the new image. What web server are you using? What is the exact URL where you expect to find "hello.js"? The older images had the browser looking for `http://localhost:3000/hello.js` - is that really the URL for the file? If not, what is it? When you type that URL into a new browser tab, what do you get?

Comment: I'm using node. I never expect hello.js to be in the url, just a relay between the api and the html. I want it to display on localhost:3000/test+(whatever id they enter). If I typed what you put into my browser, I would expect nothing and get nothing. I think that is the problem - the browser is looking for http://localhost:3000/hello.js when it shouldnt.

Comment: It's doing that because that's how `<script>` tags work. AJAX also works via URLs. It's definitely possible for your Node server code to route any URL any way it wants, but you still have to make sure that the client-side code is creating and using the URLs the server expects.

Comment: So since it expects http://localhost:3000/hello.js, should I add something like an app.get(/hello.js) to the main controller with the other routes? What would I put inside it, just a redirect to the /test page?

Comment: If you put a redirect to the test page, you'll get the same results. When the browser asks for "hello.js", the server should respond with the contents of "hello.js".

Comment: @Pointy Then I don't quite understand what to do. I'm really lost about making this rest call go smoothly

Comment: An AJAX call is just an ordinary HTTP call that you control from JavaScript; that's it. You send a URL to the server with the expectation that the server will respond with something you expect. The browser also issues implicit HTTP requests for `<link>` tags (CSS) and `<script>` tags (JavaScript) and `<img>` tags (images), and other similar things. Like I said before, it may help to start with a simpler situation just to make sure you can load your main page and static auxiliary content reliably.

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to include 3 different copies of jquery, and 2 of them are incorrectly formatted.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/html"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "hello.js"></script>
```

- the first line is incorrect, because the `type='text/html`, this is not a text file.
- the second line is looking for a local file, but its easier to use the cdn.

the 3rd is good. delete the first two lines.

To clarify whats happening... Right now you're trying to help your browser download javascript files, and it cannot find them. You need to make sure all these files are being served properly from your local computer or use a cdn.

Comment: @Blair_Anderson I deleted those lines, and no doubt it cleared up some errors, but I am left with that awful error at the top for which I have no explanation.

Comment: @WillAshley thats because you have html inside of a .js file. you need to put html inside a .html file and js inside .js